# nexus repo showing insufficient trend data when i did analyzing its showing this msg

Tags: nexus

Nexus repo showing insufficient trend data when I did analyze its showing this msg.

My nexus is OSS version.

[image]

Comment: Hover your mouse over the "insufficient tend data", the tooltip gives the explanation...  which is, there aren't enough days worth of data yet to construct the trend graph.

Comment: @rseddon if you make this the answer, I'll upvote it=)  You deserve it=)